# Finding Path in graph( specific Length)

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory

we are looking for an algorithm, that can find a path in a undirected weighted graph (from 's' to 't' for instance), that the total weights of all it's edges is a fixed number ('m' for instance)
ideas.. anyone?

Comment: Does the path have to be simple? If it does I don't think you'll find a deterministic solution (as the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path) problem would reduce to it). Also, do you have any limits on the edge weights?

Comment: Do you also have negative weights?

Comment: Good problem. Where does it come from? Any research on the part of the poster?

Comment: Thanks. 
the path shouldn't be simple. and all the weights are positive.

Comment: With the clarifications posted in the comments this problem can be solved with dynamic programming within `|V|*m` memory bound. Unfortunately I cannot convince myself that this problem is not homework to justify giving away any further details.

Comment: with floyd warshall\ bellman ford?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like DFS and backtracking. If you exceed weight m and your not at your goal, you backtrack. I'm not sure if you allow going back and forth between two nodes, but if you do, you can't build a tree in place but have to build a stack.

I have a gut feeling that first searching the shortest path and then making it longer would be a faster approach, but the same feeling tells me that it could be wrong like greedy algos are wrong for the Travelling Salesman.

Comment: There are two interpretations of this: One could be that you can only visit each edge once, the other that you can only visit each vertex once. Anyhow, just use a DFS and you should get a solution. Just mark each edge or vertex accordingly on visit and unmark it while backtracking.